# Splitting a c++ string into two parts

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to split a string that contains "|" into two parts.

```
if (size_t found = s.find("|") != string::npos)
{
    cout << "left side = " << s.substr(0,found) << endl;
    cout << "right side = " << s.substr(found+1, string::npos) << endl;

}
```

This works with "a|b", but with "a | b", it will have "| b" as the right side. Why is that? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
size_t found = s.find("|") != string::npos
```

This is a declaration; it gets parsed as

```
size_t found = (s.find("|") != string::npos)
```

So, `found` will always be `1` or `0`.  You need to declare `found` outside of the condition and use some parentheses:

```
size_t found;
if ((found = s.find("|")) != string::npos)
```

Comment: Yet another operator lower than == in precedence. :p

Comment: Is there a way to put the declaration of found inside the if statement?

Comment: @wilhelmtell Not an operator.  As James McNellis said, `size_t found = ...` is a declaration.  The `=` is part of the grammar of the declaration, and is not an operator.

Comment: @Phenom Not immediately.  But why would you want to, other than for obfuscation?

Comment: For optimal readability, I'd suggest `size_t found = s.find("|"); if(found != string::npos) { ... }`

Comment: This code is actually part of a a series for if-else statements. I thought it would be better to declare found where it is used rather than before.